# In Eclipse RAP how to push/force current UI state to the client?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rap

I'm using Eclipse RAP and have the following use case:

- enter search text in a `Text` field and start search
- change a `Label` text to *"searching...."*
- do actual search (async) and display result in a `Table`

The problem, even though the label should change to *"searching...."* before the actual search is started, it is changed to *"searching...."* after the search is done.

What I'm looking for is a way to push/force/update the current UI state to the client after the label changed, prior to searching:

- enter search text in a `Text` field and start search
- change a `Label` text to *"searching...."*
- **push current UI state to client**
- do actual search (async) and display result in a `Table`

Here some sample code:

```
    Label statusLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    Text searchText = new Text(parent, SWT.SEARCH);
    searchText.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // change label
            statusLabel.setText("searching...");

            // HERE force client update

            // start searching
            Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do actual search
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncExec` still runs the code in the UI thread it just delays it slightly until the next call to `Display.readAndDispatch`. So your search code will still block and isn't allowing the label to update.

You need to actually run the search in a separate thread.

`asyncExec` is intended to be used in a background thread to run a small amount of code in the UI thread when possible. (You need to use `Display.getDefault()` rather than `Display.getCurrent()` in a background thread).

So in your background thread you do something like:

```
while (more to do)
 {
   .... do a step of the search

   Display.getDefault().asyncExec(.... UI update code ....);
 }
```

Comment: If I run the search in a separated thread, I will not be able to access the UI right? e.g. updating status Label, update Result Table. I would run into an "Invalid thread access" Exception, I guess?

Comment: You use `asyncExec` (or `syncExec`) in the background thread to run your UI update code - that is what it is for.

Comment: Display.getDefault() and Display.getCurrent() were both null in the thread, I had to store it as variable before starting the thread.